# Grouping Deeply Nested Objects Using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by

I have the following classes:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public PriceList List { get; set; }
}

public class PriceList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially, it's for a list of items [`Item`] in which each item has a list of prices [`List<Price> Prices`] (one-to-many), and each price has one price list [`PriceList List`] (one-to-one).

What I need is a list of all price lists.

It seems like what I need is a group to a "grandchild", basically, grouping by the `PriceList`'s `Id` (which is under `Price`, which in turn is under `Item` in the list).

So, as an example, if I have five price lists, it should return five rows.

I achieved it doing the following long way:

```
List<PriceList> priceLists = new List<PriceList>();

foreach (Item item in items)
{
    foreach (Price price in item.Prices)
    {
        PriceList list = price.List;

        if (!priceLists.Any(x => x.Id == list.Id))
        {
            priceLists.Add(list);
        }
    }
}
```

How can it be achieved using LINQ?

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a basic sample set:

```
PriceList priceList1 = new PriceList { Id = 1, FileName = "Price List 1.csv" };
PriceList priceList2 = new PriceList { Id = 2, FileName = "Price List 2.csv" };

Price price1 = new Price { Id = 1, Cost = 2.65, List = priceList1 };
Price price2 = new Price { Id = 2, Cost = 14.23, List = priceList2 };
Price price3 = new Price { Id = 3, Cost = 29.01, List = priceList1 };
Price price4 = new Price { Id = 4, Cost = 1, List = priceList2 };
Price price5 = new Price { Id = 5, Cost = 56.12, List = priceList1 };

Item item1 = new Item { Id = 1, Sku = "item1", Prices = new List<Price> { price1, price2 } };
Item item2 = new Item { Id = 2, Sku = "item2", Prices = new List<Price> { price3, price4 } };
Item item3 = new Item { Id = 3, Sku = "item3", Prices = new List<Price> { price5 } };

List<Item> itemsList = new List<Item> { item1, item2, item3 };
```

Let's start from the bottom upwards:

1. I have a list of `Item` (`itemsList`), which contains three `Item`s.
2. Each `Item` has a list of `Price`.
3. Each `Price` has one `PriceList`.

To clarify the reasoning behind all this: The user imports a spreadsheet of prices (price list) they get periodically from their supplier, prices fluctuate and each price list has different prices for the same items. Hence the reason of having an item with many prices and each price has its price list which was used to upload it (there's more information included in the `PriceList` class which I omitted to keep it simple).

I hope I'm clear.

Comment: So `Price` -> `PriceList` is not really *one-to-one*, but *many-to-one*, ending up with `Item` -> `PriceList`  being *many-to-many* through `Price`. And `PriceList` objects with the same `Id` are not one and the same instance?

Comment: Is your current approach yielding the Grouped result set? I can see only one record for each PriceList Id (when I keep some repeating PriceList Ids).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you want, using an extension to do Distinct by a lambda expression:

```
var ans = itemsList.SelectMany(item => item.Prices.Select(price => price.List)).DistinctBy(price => price.Id);
```

The extension is as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keyFun) {
    var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (T e in src)
        if (seenKeys.Add(keyFun(e)))
            yield return e;
}
```

If you changed your approach to use a `HashSet<Int>` to track the seen ids you would probably be a tiny bit more efficient than LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can combine a `SelectMany` (to get all the `Prices` lists) with a `Select` (to get all the associated `PriceList` properties):

```
List<PriceList> priceLists = items.SelectMany(i => i.Prices).Select(p => p.List).ToList();
```

**Edit**

The above will return all the `PriceLists`, but since many `Items` could reference the same `PriceList`, then you need a way to filter on the `PriceList.Id` field.

One way to do that would be to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` property of the `PriceList` object. If you truly consider two `PriceList` objects to be equal if they have the same `Id`, then you could do the following:

```
public class PriceList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportDateTime { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as PriceList;
        return Id == other?.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

This allows you to use the `Linq` method, `Distinct` on your prices (it will call the `Equals` method to distinguish between `PriceLists` in the results:

```
List<PriceList> priceLists = items
    .SelectMany(i => i.Prices)
    .Select(i => i.List)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This gives me back a price list for each price, so if I have one thousand prices, I get one thousand price lists in return.

Comment: You said, *"So, as an example, if I have five price lists, it should return five rows."*

Comment: I have "prices" and I have "price lists", one item can have many price lists and each price list has only one price per item. So if I have five "price lists" it should return five rows (not if I have five "prices" it should return five rows).

Comment: Oh, I think I see. Many `Prices` could reference the same `PriceList`. Are you able to modify the `PriceList` object to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Yes, many `Prices` could reference the same `PriceList`. No, I haven't tried overriding anything, how would I go about it?

Comment: Updated answer with a potential solution

Comment: Same result as the original response :-(

Comment: Not for me...I only get back PriceLists with unique PriceList Ids. Can you update your question with some sample data so we're looking at the same thing?

Comment: Thanks! Using your data, I get the exact same results with my code as I do with your code. What difference are you seeing?

Comment: Hmm, using my sample set and your code I get the correct results, too :-) I'll have to see where I'm going wrong.